# How to interpret p-value?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

Let’s consider a example: $\text{Pr}(H_0 \text{ is true}\mid\text{reject } H_0)$. This has a direct, simple meaning: it’s the probability with which we should believe $H_0$ is false given that we rejected it. We directly care about this, because we can calculate the utility of decisions that depend on whether or not $H_0$ is true.

But how am I supposed to usefully interpret p-values? Say we perform an experiment and the p-value is 0.05. The definition is $\text{Pr}(\text{reject } H_0 \mid H_0 \text{ is true})$, i.e., if $H_0$ was true, how likely are we to falsely reject it. Why do we directly care about this?

I understand that in some vague, hand-wavy sense, the lower the p-value, the more ‘confident’ we should be in our experiment, but there’s seems to be a disconnect between the p-value and useful takeaways. What am I missing?

Comment: So: what would you do in situations where there is no prior available?  I am voting to close because this is a contentious subject that is being addressed somewhat polemically and vaguely and therefore is likely to invite answers that do not meet our site standards.

Comment: @whuber Use a uniform prior, or in the binary case, $\text{Bernoulli}(\frac 12)$? I don’t intend to start a Bayesian/frequentist war. I just want to understand how to interpret p-value.

Comment: @whuber See edit. If you still feel it should be on hold, I’ll try to find a different way of answering my question, but if it’s more appropriate for StackEchange now, let me know!

Comment: Thank you for working at this.  I think it would help to acknowledge some of the highest-voted posts on our site that address the same question so we can see how yours might differ from them.  Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value?sort=votes.

Answer (score 5):

Statistical significance is not a probability, it is a declaration or a decision. The p-value *is* a probability, and it is commonly taught that an experiment is *declared* statistically significant if the p-value is small. The p-value quantifies the likelihood of the evidence, in a sense, under a set of assumptions. If the probability is small, the data are assumed to be inconsistent with those assumptions. The probability statement you've is just the type 1 error rate: i.e. P(reject H_0 | H_0 is true) is the alpha level of a test, $\alpha$.

This agrees with the Popperian way of doing science which, at its core, does not believe we can ever measure, as an event "H_0 is true". That's because H_0 is not a random event, but a fact of reality. As such, it doesn't matter what we declare to be the truth. So P(H_0 is true | declare H_0 false) doesn't make any sense.